# Detect not accessibility of iCloud from iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, icloud, icloud-drive

I've developing app which is using iCloud for backup and restore of app's data.
For that I'm using following code to access iCloud for writing my data in it.

```
    if let iCloudDocumentsURL = FileManager.default.url(forUbiquityContainerIdentifier: nil) {
        var iCloudDocumentsURL = iCloudDocumentsURL
        do {
            iCloudDocumentsURL = iCloudDocumentsURL.appendingPathComponent("Documents")
            try FileManager.default.createDirectory(at: iCloudDocumentsURL, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
        }
        catch {
            completion(false, error.localizedDescription)
        }
        let fileURL = iCloudDocumentsURL.appendingPathComponent(file)
        //writing
        do {
            try text.write(to: fileURL, atomically: false, encoding: .utf8)
            completion(true, nil)
        }
        catch {
            completion(false, error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
    else {
        completion(false, "iCloud is not accessible")
    }
```

But if user is not logged in iCloud then it also giving me "iCloud is not accessible" or if user logged in iCloud but disable iCloud access for my app then also I'm getting same message.

So, is there anyway how can I detect similar like this error with different status. Cause I want to give appropriate message to user so he can use some of feature of my app.
I also wonder how can I detect if user's iCloud storage is full and I'm trying to write in iCloud storage.
how can I detect available space of iCloud?

Answer (score 1):

There is a number of different iCloud error codes which are specified [in the Apple Developer Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/icloud/icloud_error_codes).

The one you are interested in specifically is `NSUbiquitousFileNotUploadedDueToQuotaError`:

> NSUbiquitousFileNotUploadedDueToQuotaError
>   The item could not be uploaded to iCloud because it would make the account go over its
>   quota.

Comment: When this error would throw? I mean when I try to write in iCloud? Should I add any more code to handle these errors? Or my try catch block will enough?

Comment: @MrugeshTank you can follow the link in my answer to see details. It says that `NSUbiquitousFileNotUploadedDueToQuotaError` is thrown if "The item could not be uploaded to iCloud because it would make the account go over its quota." So yes, it would throw when you try to write to iCloud.

Answer (score 0):

Your first `if` statement is failing every time because you need to provide an actual string value as the container identifier.

See the docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filemanager/1411653-url):

> If you specify nil for this parameter, this method returns the first
>   container listed in the
>   com.apple.developer.ubiquity-container-identifiers entitlement array.

Do you definitely have the entitlement array in your `info.plist`? This is needed to make this work. Alternatively declare it as a string.

---

You can check if an iCloud account is available by checking the [`ubiquityIdentityToken`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filemanager/1408036-ubiquityidentitytoken) property.

> To determine if iCloud is available, especially at launch time, check
>   the value of the ubiquityIdentityToken property instead.

This token will change if the user changes the account they use on the device. It will return `nil` if an account is not available.

Comment: I can access iCloud when user logged in and enable access for my app. There is no any problem in code for access. I just want to handle error properly.

Comment: Should I check first ubiquityIdentityToken for check iCloud logged in or not, and then  check for iCloud URL? or something else you're suggesting?